# Why doesn't my list populated from a database refresh unless I restart my Flask server?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a very simple flask app the allows me to register usernames and then displays these names in a list. I can register, but the list will be empty. If I restart the flask server the names appear as they should upon page load. I have tried closing/reopening the database, calling a function (populateuserlist) to refresh the list, and disabling browser caching in the html to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

*app.py*

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, render_template_string
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired, length
import sqlite3
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
c = conn.cursor()
#create users.db if it doesn't exist
try:
    c.execute("""CREATE TABLE users (
            username text UNIQUE
            )""")
    print("users.db created with users table")
except:
    print("users.db file exists")

c.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
userlist=c.fetchall()
conn.close()

#populate userlist from users.db
def populateuserlist():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    userlist = c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return userlist

#form with drop down list for users page
class selectuserform(FlaskForm):
    populateuserlist()
    userlist = populateuserlist()
    print("Login form populated with" + str(userlist) + ".")
    currentuser = SelectField('currentuser', choices=[(user[0], user[0]) for user in userlist])

class RegisterNameForm(FlaskForm):
    RegisterName = StringField('Username', validators= [InputRequired(), length(min=1, max=15)])

#define page routes
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    form = RegisterNameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newuser=request.form.get("RegisterName")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users VALUES (?)", (newuser,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    form = selectuserform()
    populateuserlist()

    return render_template('login.html', userlist=userlist, form=form)

@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
    form = RegisterNameForm()
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)

#start flask server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

*login.html*

```
<!<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

</head>
<body>
<div>
    <button onclick="window.location.href = '/register'";>Register</button>
    <center>
        <h1>Select User</h1>
<form method="POST" ACTION="{{ url_for('login_page') }}">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.currentuser }}
    <br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
    </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

*register.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="window.location.href = '/login'";>Go back</button>
    <center>
        <h1>Enter your name</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="/login">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ form.RegisterName }}
            <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Create user">
        </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be working with global values like this in a web app, it leaves you open to all sorts of wonky behaviour. This function:

```
def populateuserlist():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
    userlist = c.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return userlist
```

Does nothing to the global `userlist` name. Why should it? You create a new name in the local function scope. I'm *deliberately* skipping over the use of `global` and you shouldn't be tempted to use it. You can test the scope issue easily with:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

def something():
    a = [2, 3, 4]
    return a

something()
print(a)
```

As such, `userlist` (the global) is evaluated only once when the app starts. Instead, you need to call `populateuserlist` (which should be renamed accordingly since it doesn't doesn't populate the global name) within the view. The issue is also present in your form. You'll need to dynamically update the list of options.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login_page():
    form = RegisterNameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        newuser=request.form.get("RegisterName")
        conn = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO users VALUES (?)", (newuser,))
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()

    form = selectuserform()
    userlist = populateuserlist() # CHANGED HERE
    form.currentuser.choices = [(user[0], user[0]) for user in userlist] # ADD THE NEW OPTIONS (IF ANY)

    return render_template('login.html', userlist=userlist, form=form)
```

Comment: I have added userlist = populateuserlist() but it still does not refresh. I also added print(userlist) below that and the console does reflect that the database and userlist values are being updated correctly but the drop down list does not reflect the changes. Thank you for the excellent explanation of global vs local variables as well, I am very new to python. What would be a more appropriate name for the populateuserlist function?

Comment: @Bob the last part is simple; `get_userlist()` is a better name, but let me review the code again because maybe I missed something on the front end

Comment: @Bob got it. Give me a few minutes to edit, I did indeed miss something

Comment: @Bob Edited but not tested. Let me know if that works

Comment: Works great, thank you for the insight on the function naming as well.

Comment: @Bob no problem :) You can ditch the global on start up now you're doing the query dynamically and eventually you'll probably want to move to SQLAlchemy but at least this part is sorted